# How to convert Type in a visually decent, visual-studio-style string

Tags: c#, reflection

I've written a reflection tool to analyze the interface hierarchy of our data model.

On my custom class I have a `List<Type>`, which contains all the properties I want to display. I wrote a `PropertyWrapper` class, to make it easier for me to display these certain properties nicely:

```
public class PropertyWrapper
{
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public PropertyWrapper(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;

        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            PropertyNameString = propertyInfo.Name;

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                PropertyTypeString = propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.Split('`').First().Split('.').Last()
                                     + "<"
                                     + propertyInfo.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First()
                                                   .FullName.Split('.')
                                                   .Last()
                                     + ">";
            else
                PropertyTypeString = propertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName.Split('.').Last();
        }
    }
}
```

My Xaml is this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="PropertyWrapper">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyType}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyName}" Margin="5 0 0 0" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My aim was to be able to display certain properties in a Visual Studio alike style. The problem is not the property name, more likely it's the `PropertyType`, which looks actually like this (`.ToString()`): `System.Collections.Generic.IList'1[System.Object]`. But what I'd like is a string like this: `IList<Object>` (actually `IList<object>`, but let's not be too perfectionistic).

My question is, due to I execute this code very often, is there a more efficient/elegant way to achieve this? I was thinking, that this reflection code might not scale, if our codebase becomes larger and larger.

I'd be also glad of critics regarding this reflection code, either, due to I'm pretty new to reflection. Where could it fail, where could I write safer code? It's no production code, though, just a tool for developers.

One point to say about the code, which is reflected is, that there aren't any generic types with multiple generic arguments in it.

**EDIT**

A little question regarding stackoverflow code block formatting. Can I escape the "`" character in inline codeblocks somehow? Not using it as a code block initializer, but rather as a normal character in my text, it almost messed up my formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be much concerned about the speed of the "string processing".

Reflection operation are much slower, so focus on how to reduce that time.

You can use 2 approach:

1) Use reflection only assembly use loading (it is quicker:

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()
```

2) Cache the results using the assembly unique signature and save results to  a file (i.e. using serialization), so you don't need to reload already parsed assembies.

Hope this helps

Comment: I never used serialization, yet. Does this mean, the unique signature of the assembly changes, as soon as its code changes? So I don't need to keep the cached stuff in sync with the code structure of the assembly?

Comment: No, serialization is used to save an object (and nested propertied) in a specific format (i.e. an xml file). Once you have saved it you can retrieve it using deserialization. See XmlSerializator class for example

Comment: And yes, the signature of an assembly changes. You can use an Hashing algorithm to compute the signature and check for changes.

Comment: Alright, I have been in touch with this already, it wasn't stored under `Serialization`, though. :)